# Can I mention the weak points of the department I am applying for in my cover letter?

Tags: faculty-application

I am applying for a faculty position in a small department, which is not very active in research but there is a strategic research. Comparing my previous papers and grants, I can project that I will have a significant contribution to the department to become research active.

Is it appropriate to provide a statistical projection that how the department figures will be changed by hiring me? I mean isn't it impolite to highlight the weak points of the department to justify why they should hire me?

Comment: The title doesn't really match the question. You aren't mentioning weak points. You're expressing what you can bring. Albeit, in doing so, you might be highlighting that you're above average. The first thing we should address is: is it reasonable to highlight your impact on departmental figures? I think it would be better to highlight your impact and let others infer the departmental impact. E.g., state that you've previously published X and won Y grants, and you expect to publish X' and Y' in the coming year. By explaining your impact, you needn't directly raise weak points of the department.

Answer (score 7):

Don't mention anything negative about the department you're applying to. That would serious jeopardize your application.

Instead, emphasize the benefits that hiring you could bring to the department. Do this in a way that pleases the current members of the department.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can possibly know how hiring you will impact their department figures, and trying to do that without understanding the full situation would look extremely arrogant.

Even if you believe that you know the reasons, there might be other factors which are not public knowledge. For instance, I know one department at a university I worked with slowed down research as they were getting ready for a merger.

State your worth - and state it strongly - but don't make any assumptions of concrete or statistical improvements you can bring.

Answer (score 1):

Cover letter is more suitable for stating your intention. It might come as arrogant if you give your ideas for department without asked first or becoming part of the department.